# Emoji not displayed in deployed Hugo website (Netlify)

Tags: emoji, netlify, hugo, blogdown

I have deployed my Hugo website (build in RStudio with `blogdown`) on Netlify and noticed that I am missing (some of) the emoji that I added in the title/subtitle [see https://new-blog-2020.netlify.app/ ]

This does not happen when I run the site locally (`blogdown::server_site()`)

[image]

How can I fix this? If it matters, my theme is [hugo-lamp](https://github.com/huyb1991/hugo-lamp)

EDIT:

header.html

```
  <h1 class="title"><a href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}" title="{{ .Site.Title }}">{{ .Site.Title | emojify }}</a></h1>
  {{ else }}
    <h2 class="title"><a href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}" title="{{ .Site.Title }}">{{ .Site.Title | emojify}}</a></h2>
  {{ end }}
  <p class="subtitle">{{ .Site.Params.subtitle | emojify}}</p>
```

config.toml

```
[params]
  mainSections = ["posts"] # determine which sections are displayed on the homepage
  subtitle = "Here is where I have fun with </br> data :bar_chart: (and) :microbe: science :dna: :microscope:"
  author = "Nick"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use emoji in some titles[*] of articles on my Hugo-based site and after a lot of experiments have decided that for me the best solution is to use Unicode characters rather than emoji codes[^] ***in titles***. For example, instead of `:dna:` and `:microbe:`, you could use the Unicode characters  and  in your title and subtitle.

An alternative is to edit the relevant layout file so that instead of, for example, `{{ .Title }}` it says `{{ .Title |emojify }}`.

In any case, make sure your editor, source and destination files, web server, and web browser are all using [UTF-8](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.

I hope this helps!

[*] For example [Introduction to Hugo Bundles](https://www.ii.com/hugo-bundles/) and [AsciiDoc Kitchen Sink (featuring )](https://www.ii.com/asciidoc-kitchen-sink/)

[^] To use emoji codes in Hugo, you need `enableEmoji: true` in your `config.yaml`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions... Can I ask you how exactly do I add an emoji using the Unicode characters?

I do have the emojify string in the Title and Subtitle variables, and locally they all work fine. It's just in the deployed version that some emoji don't render at all... I checked the encoding in the HTML and it is already in UTF8

Comment: That's weird that they work locally but not on Netlify?! Anyway, you need to copy & paste the actual Unicode character from somewhere. My default place for that is http://www.fileformat.info/. Here's what you get if you search for `dna`: [Unicode Character 'DNA DOUBLE HELIX' (U+1F9EC)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f9ec/index.htm). You can copy it from the "Input test" field on https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f9ec/browsertest.htm. Another option is to use the `:dna:` emoji code in the body of one of your Hugo pages and then copy the char from the rendered page.